# Do all the pointer variables inside a program got deleted after sudden crash?

Tags: c++, linux, networking, ip-camera

I have an IP based Camera( basler Ace2000-50gm) connected to an embedded board which runs ubuntu 12.04 64bit . I managed to configure it according to its documentation and now I can grab frames at any frame rate with any kind of parameters I like. (I used C++ APIs)

Here is the initializing Code:

```
typedef Pylon::CBaslerGigEInstantCamera Camera_t;
void Cam_Init()
{
    bool Camera_Initialization = false;
    Camera_t *Camera;
    Camera = new Camera_t();
    PylonInitialize();
    do{
        if(!Camera_Initialization)
        {
            try
            {

                CTlFactory& tlFactory = CTlFactory::GetInstance();

                // Get all attached devices and exit application if no device is found.
                DeviceInfoList_t devices;
                qDebug("Detecting Camera ....");
                if ( tlFactory.EnumerateDevices(devices) == 0 )
                {
                    throw RUNTIME_EXCEPTION( "No camera present.");
                }
                Camera  = new Camera_t(  tlFactory.CreateDevice( devices[0 ]) );
                Camera->Open();
                CAcquireContinuousConfiguration().OnOpened( *Camera);
                Camera->StartGrabbing( GrabStrategy_UpcomingImage);
                Camera_Initialization = true;
                qDebug("Camera is Configured Successfully");
            }
            catch( GenericException &e )
            {
                Interface<<  "****  An exception occurred! Desription is: " << "\n"<< "    " << e.GetDescription() << "\n";

            }
        }
    }while(!Camera_Initialization);
}
```

This code is part of a large program.

The Problem is that my program crashes suddenly (I haven't found its sourceyet) and when I rerun my code it doesn't detect the camera till 5 minutes or more has passed since its last crash !!! it gives the following error message

```
****  An exception occurred! Desription is: 
    Failed to open 'Basler acA2000-50gm#00305316A684#10.136.18.100:3956'. The device is controlled by another application. Err: GX status 0xe1018006 (0xE1018006)
```

as you have seen my code for initializing the camera,I've used a pointer object to connect to my camera and I think when the code crashes this pointer is not deleted so the camera is not available !

I also think it's kind of network problem and I don't know how to solve it. When My program crashesh I tried every different way to restart networking services in the Ubuntu such as:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
. 
.
.
```

but none of them worked for me and still when my program crashes it takes more than 5 minutes to be able to run my program.

It is amazing that after 5 minutes my code detects the camera correctly and I'm able to run my code. I tried for zillion times and I must stay at least 5 minutes to run the code to detect the camera !!!(It repeats to show the above error message for the next 5 minute )  I ran this code many times in my own laptop and PC but after the code crash I can run the code without any problem so I think the problem lies with the embedded board network !

I thought every kind of variables gets deleted after terminating a program but it seems it's kind of wrong to think so !

I can provide any information you want to solve this problem.
thanks

Comment: Isolate your crashing code from the code that interacts with the camera using a service process. When your main process crashes, the service process can shut down cleanly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Can you show me some useful references for getting familiar with writing these kind of services. I don't know how should I Start and where to look at.

Answer (score 2):

The memory is freed, but destructors will not be run.  Probably,
the destructor informs the system that it is no longer
controlling the device.

I would consider this a bug in the system.  The fact that
a specific process is controlling the device should behave much
like an `open`, and if the process crashes, it would be
detached.  (Under Unix, this could be done by implementing it as
some sort of pseudo-device, for example.)

Comment: Thanks but how can I close an open method which has been called in the previous run ?!!! Where should I report this bug ?!?!

Comment: Is there any way to close an open method ?! suppose a text file which is opened by an unknown process and I want to write into it. is there any way to do it ?

Comment: @PsP You'll have to contact the suppliers of the board, or the system for it.  They obviously have some custom extensions to Linux, and they are responsible for documenting and maintaining them.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I suspect they don't use extensions. The camera is called an "IP camera" and the error message refers to `10.136.18.100:3956`. I'll bet that's a TCP/IP port and address. That's just handled by an ordinary socket. But the camera may not support two open TCP connections, which means the Linux board must disconnect cleanly.

Comment: @JamesKanze So you mean the problem is caused by the linux OS installed on the embedded board ?

Comment: @MSalters Linux normally disconnects a socket if the process owning it terminates, for whatever reason.  Are you saying that it takes the system 5 minutes for the FIN/ACK exchange needed for a clean shutdown of the socket?  Or that for some reasons, this Linux isn't closing the socket when the process dies.

Comment: @PsP It could be.  I don't know how you're actually communicating with the device at the system level, but normally, it should be something that looks more or less like a file, and which should be automatically closed when your process crashes.  Depending on the device, it may take a little time to actually close it, but that amount of time should be something you would measure in milliseconds, not minutes.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It's not my setup. I don't know if there's anything interfering with `FIN/ACK` sending. I know that TCP connection closing is complex, and I wouldn't be surprised if the camera is subtly non-conforming. As for the 5 minutes, that sounds like a typical duration of `TIME_WAIT` state.

Comment: @MSalters It certainly sounds like a time-out somewhere.  If there are no errors outside of his process, and his process is running under an implementation of Unix, there _should_ be no time-outs in deconstructing the TCP connection; the TCP connection itself is managed by the OS, not his process, and when the "file" is closed (as it should be by the system when he crashes), then the TCP connection should be shut down normally.  If it really is a TCP connection, I see two possibilities for his symptoms: a bug in his OS, or he has received the _fd_ from another process, which still has it open.

Answer (score 2):

C++ standard (§18.3/8): "Automatic objects are not destroyed as a result of calling exit()."
"Terminates the process normally, performing the regular cleanup for terminating processes."
Where regular cleanup is destruction of static objects and not dynamically allocated ones.

To get around this You can try fooling around with signal handlers and disconnect there if you have the pointer to camera somewhere.

While you try that I found a memory leak!

```
Camera = new Camera_t();
```

and

```
       Camera  = new Camera_t(  tlFactory.CreateDevice( devices[0 ]) );
```

with no free between. Also there is no return of Camera so I must assume that

```
            CAcquireContinuousConfiguration().OnOpened( *Camera);
```

somehow has the address of `Camera`, else there is another leak.

[Signal handlers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/?kw=signal)

If you have some global way to access your device, then one of the signal handlers might be able to catch your error, if a `try-catch` in main can't.

Comment: Good point to mention ! I'll test it to see if I've found the root of the evil !! Anyway can you explain a little more about your first statement "try fooling around with signal handlers ..." what do you mean exactly by saying that and What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

This failure has nothing to do with C++ or any other programming language, nor is it related to the operating system. Actually this is intended behvaiour by the Basler Pylon API. The reason for that is, that the communication is done via UDP. This is a connectionless network protocol. In order to know that the counterpart is still existing, the Basler camera protocol driver (in your network interface) will cyclically send some data, a.k.a. heartbeat message. The default heartbeat timeout is 3000ms, but during debugging it is automatically increased to 5 minutes. Therefore it takes about 5 minutes until the camera knows that the original connection is lost and it allows another connection to be made.

(From the Pylon.Net help)

> ### Debugging pylon Applications Using GigE Cameras
>
> When debugging a pylon application using GigE cameras, you may encounter so-called "heartbeat" timeouts. The application must send special network packets to the camera in defined intervals. If the camera doesn't receive these heartbeats in time, it will consider the connection as broken and won't accept any commands from the application.
>
> To work around this problem, you have to extend the heartbeat timeout during development. You can do this by setting the PYLON_GIGE_HEARTBEAT environment variable. This will instruct pylon to change the heartbeat interval to the given value when opening the camera. Alternatively, you can set the HeartbeatTimeout property of the camera transport layer in your code.
>
> ```
> Copycamera.Parameters[PLTransportLayer.HeartbeatTimeout].TrySetValue(1000, IntegerValueCorrection.Nearest);  // 1000 ms timeout
> ```
>
> When running under a debugger, the pylon GigE transport layer automatically sets the heartbeat timeout of a device to 5 minutes. This can be overridden by setting the PYLON_GIGE_HEARTBEAT environment variable. We recommend not to rely on the default mechanism but to explicitly specify the heartbeat timeout by setting an appropriate heartbeat timeout as described above.
>
> **Caution**
>   *If you have set the heartbeat timeout to a high value and stop your application without closing the device properly by calling the Close()  method, you won't be able to open the camera again. Also, you will receive an error stating the device is currently in use. This can happen if you stop your application using the debugger. To open the camera again, you must either wait until the timeout elapses or disconnect the network cable from the camera.*